# Jquery mobile 1.4.5 dynamically change theme of button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to change the theme of buttons with jquery but for some reason it doesn't work with `$("#btn").button("option", "theme", "a");`.

I tried different versions of buttons such as `<button>` or `<input>` and the `<a>`version i can't use because of design reasons. When i use the `<button>` the script crashes (somehow i can't call the function button on a button...) and with the `<input>`it works only oneway. Somehow I can change the theme from "a" to "b" but not from "b" to "a". I also tried it with a custom theme and I noticed its somehow only possible to change the theme in increasing lexicographical order.

I also tried it on radio buttons with `$("#radio").checkboxradio("option", "theme", 'a');` and there it works both ways.

Here is a jsfiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/cfqgn8gw/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQM button widget is only for `<input>` dom elements buttons and anchors are styled but not initialized as jQM widgets.

You can easily switch themes by removing and adding a single CSS class:

```
function change_a() {
    $("#radio").checkboxradio("option", "theme", 'a').checkboxradio("refresh");

    $("#input, #btn").closest(".ui-btn").removeClass("ui-btn-b").addClass("ui-btn-a");
}

function change_b() {
    $("#radio").checkboxradio("option", "theme", 'b').checkboxradio("refresh");

    $("#input, #btn").closest(".ui-btn").removeClass("ui-btn-a").addClass("ui-btn-b");
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/cfqgn8gw/2/)**

Comment: Thank you, I tried it also with the classes before but didn't get it to work.